# Parse geolocation query with optional locations

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Using Parse query .near

```
// ...userLocation set with Lat Lon
var locationQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
locationQuery.near("location", userLocation);
```

This query will return results for users near the userLocation, but looks like it will never return results with a null location.

Would it be possible to include users without a location set in the same query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, by adding the location constraint to the query the results will be limited to objects which have a location value.

You could include other users which don't have a location set by using a [compound query](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-compound-queries) (only counts as 1 API request) and [or the queries together](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html#.or).

Here's a quick example:

```
// Location based query
var locationQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
locationQuery.near("location", userLocation);

// Query based on some other constraint (equalTo in this case)
var otherQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
otherQuery.equalTo("name", "JackalopeZero");

// Compound query
var compoundQuery = Parse.Query.or(locationQuery, otherQuery);
```

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot use a location constraint within a compound query. You would need to use `.near` on compoundQuery.

Comment: That's interesting, I had no idea that geoqueries could not be used with `Parse.Query.or`. I guess you're stuck with two separate queries then. One for nearby users and the other for whatever constraint you want to filter users.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely a problem as I'm using pagination so it means that you'll never get consistent numbers of results back

Comment: You could make sure that none of the locations are null. In an afterSave hook for the User class, add a check to see if the location is null and assign it to some default location if needed.

Comment: We had also considered this and its a good idea. The problem is that Parse will only sort by distance using near() or withinKilometers(). Running a worldwide sort makes the query incredibly slow so unless the location is near the user at all times, the results may not always appear in every query.